# Notifying APK from JAR

Tags: android, android-activity, jar, java-native-interface, apk

I have an APK, that imports a JAR which in-turn uses a JNI library. Once the library is done with a task, it calls back the JAR (reverse-JNI) and now I need to call back the APK as the last step in this entire chain of data flow. Is there a standard way of doing this? The JAR is a simple class (not based on activity)

This is the forward path: APK -> JAR -> JNI (done and working)

This is the backward path: JNI -> JAR (working via reverse-JNI). Now, need this

JAR -> APK (the apk is activity based). Would truly appreciate any feedback

Answer (score 0):

In jar,make a listener and implements it in APK,then register it in APK,when you need JNI->JAR->APK,just call the listener methods.